# Need files from directory with today's date

Tags: c#, path

I am trying to create a method that tells me if there is a current date's file from a parameter passed to it.

Here is my method so far:

```
DoesFileExist("c:\temp\file*.*");

private static bool DoesFileExist(string file)
{
  var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
  var nfile = Path.GetFileName(file);
  var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dir, nfile);
  foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
  }
  return true;
}
```

fileEntries is populated but what would be the best way to get the file(s) that are today's date, if they exist?

Thanks!

**EDIT1**

This is what I changed it to:

```
DoesFileExist("c:\temp\file*.*");
private static bool DoesFileExist(string file2)
{
  var resultfiles = Directory.GetFiles(file2).Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);

  if (resultfiles.Count() > 0)
  {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

The file2 ends up being c:\\temp\\file*.*.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **`linq`**

```
var resultfiles = Directory.GetFiles("c:\temp\file*.*")
                 .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am getting `Illegal characters in path.`.

Comment: which path ? i dont get it

Comment: I edited the post above with the update. I am getting an exception in resultfiles.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to change your `Directory.GetFiles("c:\temp\file*.*")` to `Directory.GetFiles(dir, nfile)`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The path should be escaped (`"C:\\temp\\file*.*"`) or it should use a verbatim string (`@"C:\temp\file*.*"`).